# ASP .NET AJAX Troubles IIS

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, iis

I have a problem with my ajax web site.

When I use it on my VS developer server it works fine but when I try it on IIS6 server it gave me some errors.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <      VM799 ScriptResource.axd?d=p6JcRyoQOCqj5Bsp6IC92EGDKdobWUrgL5FrpfmBAdDrufySdTJvC9ZYv8Xck5xTsFceCi41…:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <      VM800 ScriptResource.axd?d=p6JcRyoQOCqj5Bsp6IC92EGDKdobWUrgL5FrpfmBAdDrufySdTJvC9ZYv8Xck5xTsFceCi41…:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined   Default.aspx:62
Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined   Default.aspx:5719
```

That errors go to:

```
HTML dir="ltr"
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ScriptManager', document.getElementById('form1'));
Sys.Application.initialize();
```

I use .Net 2.0, VS 2005 and IIS6 and I have the same web.config on both sides.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just Move the `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` block containing the `Sys.*` calls lower down (to the last item before the close of the body's `<asp:Content/>` section) in the HTML on the page.